# how to go a portion of web page using a name attribute with querystring in URL

Tags: html

For example:

http://www.example.com/index.html#foo?key=value

When page is loaded, it goes to the bottom of the page. Any clue?

Comment: Why voted down?? Perhaps something more constructive, like give an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML5 you just need to set the hash to an ID of any DOM node on the page and it should move the page down in the same way as old style page anchors.

Anything after the hash can only be accessed by JavaScript so if you want to get the value of `key` you will need some JavaScript to do so.

EDIT: Here is a good tutorial for storing and retrieving several attributes from the hash string - http://www.parorrey.com/blog/php-development/get-url-hash-parameters-values-using-javascript-for-php-_request/

Comment: I think this is the right answer, but this really should be supported by web browsers. Using javascript is really an ugly and inconvenient workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about [anchor tags](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aabg020899a.htm) but you querystring is the wrong side of the hash. It should read:

> http://www.example.com/index.html?key=value#foo

Comment: This doesn't work. The page is always loaded at top of the page.

Comment: It does and it's supported by ALL browsers, have put in the anchor tag?